# Comparing the value with a value before it in the pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have a DataFrame df:

open    high    low close
187100  187100  187100  187100
188000  188000  188000  188000
188000  188000  188000  188000
188000  188000  188000  188000
188000  188000  188000  188000

.

From the above transaction history, create an Info column indicating that the Close price of each trading day is increased (value 1), decreased (value -1), equal (value 0), compared to the Close price of the previous day.

Comment: Please provide an example of the desired result to help contributors respond.

Comment: Shift, diff... This has GOT to be a duplicate, and shows no prior effort to solve the problem

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `diff` method from pandas and then map the result to an `if else` statement.

```
data = {'close': [187100, 188000, 188000, 187100, 188100]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['info'] = df['close'].diff()
df['info'] = df['info'].map(lambda x: 1 if x > 0 else -1 if x < 0 else 0)

print(df)

>>> close  info
0  187100     0
1  188000     1
2  188000     0
3  187100    -1
4  188100     1
```

Note that the first row of info column is NaN because there is nothing to compare, so it is set to 0 when mapping with the `if else` statement.